# Search via Geocoder gem with an existing google placeId for a location

Tags: google-geocoding-api, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to search for a location, using an existing google **PlaceId**.

It is referenced in the documentation to pass the param:
**google_place_id: true**

```
require 'geocoder'

Geocoder.search("ChIJLU7jZClu5kcR4PcOOO6p3I0", params: {google_place_id: true})
```

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#google-google

However only empty arrays are getting returned from the search.

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Geocoder uses a lot of apis. Google is NOT it's default. Also, you'll need an API key.
Setting API_KEY:

```
Geocoder.configure api_key: your API_KEY
```

Now you can search

```
Geocoder.search(some_places_id, lookup: :google_places_details)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the `params` keyword:

```rb
Geocoder.search("ChIJLU7jZClu5kcR4PcOOO6p3I0", { google_place_id: true })
```